# rownnumber is not displaying when toolbar serach and grouping is used

Tags: jqgrid, struts2-jquery

My problem is rownumber is not displaying when i use toolbar search and grouping togather , if i use them indivially i can see the rownnumber in the grid. 
My grid is like this

```xml
<sjg:grid id="reportGrid" gridModel="gridModel" autowidth="true" filter="true"  
    filterOptions="{stringResult:true,searchOnEnter:false,defaultSearch:'cn'}"    
    groupColumnShow="false" 
    groupField="['col','col1']" onSuccessTopics="dataLoadCompleted"
    groupText="['col: {0}       Total : {1} ','col2: {0}        Total : {1}']"
    href="rpt" formIds="reportform" loadonce="true">
    ....................................
    ....................................
    .................................
</sjg:grid>
</s:else>
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {    
         $.subscribe('gridLoadComplete', function(event, data) {
             $("#reportGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam', { ignoreCase: true});
        }); 
     });
</script>
```

Any idea what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's limitation of grouping. See [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:grouping#limitations)

> When the grouping is enabled, the following options will be set explicit into the code:
>
> - ...
> - **rownumbers = false;**
> - ...

Comment: OK thanks , can u see my others question which I edited.

Comment: @Haider: Which other question you mean?